# Error because of size of function in Objective-C

Tags: iphone

I am having a weird error message when i try to build my application for device:

```
{standard input}:3884:invalid offset, value too big (0x00000408)
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

the class that issued this error message contains a function that has a huge switch statement with contains other switch statements in its cases. It is almost 1200 lines long!!

When i commented this function out the compilations was complete. So i predict this is whats meant by " value too big" in the error message above, correct me if am wrong.

Now how do i get over this limitation? I am thinking of a way to break my function into different parts and implement them in categories of the class in different files. But am not sure it is gonna be that easy as the function only contains switch statements within a huge statement. I will look at this further but does any one else have any other suggestion?

Cheers
AF

Comment: As a slightly different approach - what is this switch attempting to achieve?

Comment: Thanks i have tracked the reputation thing:) i am new to this system.

Comment: The code parses in real time what the user is typing in a textfield and displays information based on his typing as he is typing.

Comment: Could you use some form of lookup table instead of a switch in that case?

Comment: Using look up table will be in efficient in my case. It is just like doing lexical analyzer but at real time. and if i want to use look up tables i will need to reload that data each time from file into some hash tree arrays...and that is time consuming, given the amount of data i have, and cumbersome given i have 4 levels of switch statements.

Comment: Have you looked into [(f)lex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_(software)) and [yacc/bison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc)? They'll generate C code for lexical analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, if you're using xcodebuild directly try building via the IDE as some reports seem to suggest this can help, unlikely though that may sound.

Secondly, if this is a compiler bug (it sounds like it is and there are quite a few similar reports on the hyperinternetweb), you could also try switching to using LLVM (via your projects "Compiler version" settings) and see if that makes a difference.

Finally, you could simply avoid the issue by using an if/else construct instead, painful though that will be.

**UPDATE**

To try out LLVM (instead of gcc), select your project's build target from the "Targets" section in the Groups & Files area, alt-click and select "Get info". In the window that appears then select the Build tab (if it's not already selected) and scroll down to the "C/C++ Compiler Version" setting within the Compiler Version category. You then then choose to use "LLVM compiler" instead of gcc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i dont really get what you meant by your first suggestion, what the difference between xcode build and IDE build?

Comment: I do not know what is LLVM, can you spot some light on it?

Comment: And regarding your last suggestion, i am using switch statement as it is faster than if/else statement when it comes to the assembly code generated for it hence giving better performance. (at least this is what i know in theory)

Comment: @Abolfoooud 1. Don't worry about it - you'd know if you were. 2. LLVM is a different compiler. I'll update my answer in a moment with more details. 3. That's needless (and meaningless) micro-optimisation - there's really no need for such an approach until (at the very least) the application is finished and you can then properly profile it.

Comment: I tried that LLVM but with no luck :( it seems i will need to break my logic into several categories :S